# What is the difference between an ejective consonant and a sequence of consonant + glottal stop?

Tags: phonology, phonemes, consonants, ejectives, glottal-stop

Is it just the simultaneousness? 
Also - can a sequence of say uvular stop and glottal stop become - diachronically - an uvular ejective?
Thanks :))

Comment: No. Ejective stops are co-articulated. The glottis closes at the same time as (or slightly after) the oral stop being glottalized, then the glottis rises, compressing the airspace and creating a high pressure pocket behind the oral stop. The oral stop is then released, with high-pressure expulsion of the pressurized air behind it. A sequence of oral stop plus glottal stop doesn't come close.